# How to fetch the selected element from a group of radio buttons from ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have 2 groups of radio buttons with links corresponding to each of the group in my ASP.NET MVC application.

Below is the screen-shot for better clarity:

[alt text http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/7959/radiogroups.png](http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/7959/radiogroups.png)

**When I select the appropriate link, the value associated with the particular group should be passed on to the controller Action.**

For instance in the above case, while clicking "link 1", the values A1 or A2 should passed to the controller action method.

I tried doing a post to the appropriate action method, but the value associated with the second link is also getting passed. How can I get only the selected value from the clicked link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a javascript function as the href of the link.  It would read the selected value of the corresponding radio button group and add it to a url string.  You can set the window.location or set the form action and submit.

Comment: I added the Jquery plugin instead to dynamically set the href attribute of the link.

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript you can clear the values of the other radio buttons before submitting the form.

Other solution can be having a hidden field and populating it with the appropriate value using javascript whenever a link is clicked. Then you get the value of this field and forget about the radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

Put the two radio buttons and the associated link into a separate form. Replace the link with a submit button (or submit image if you want it to look like a link). So you will have two forms both posting to the same controller action. Give your submit button a `name` which can be used inside the action to determine which button was clicked. You could also use a hidden field. The first thing to do in the action is to determine which button was clicked and then read the appropriate request values for the radio buttons.

Another alternative is to have everything in the same form with two submit buttons and different names.

Comment: Darin thanks for that , i doubt if that is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.CountryModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
            @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male" new { @checked = "checked" }) Male
            @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Female")Female
            <input type="submit" text="submit"/>
}
```

**MODEL**

```
   public class CountryModel
    {
        public string Gender{ get; set; }

    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{                    
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(CountryModel model)
{
    //for radio button
    CountryModel dd = new CountryModel();
    string date1 = model.RDB;
    return View(model);
}
```